# screen Cannot access pts/0 No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I want my script continue to run after ssh session terminate. I have no root access to server. What I tried:

```
autos@autos.tech [~/bit]# ls -la /var/run/screen/
drwxrwxrwx  4 root         screen       4096 2017-11-09 18:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 26 root         root         4096 2017-11-17 17:25 ../
drwx------  2 autos autos 4096 2017-11-09 18:48 S-autos/
drwx------  2 root         root         4096 2017-10-24 03:06 S-root/
```

...

```
autos@autos.tech [~/bit]# ls -la /var/run/screen/S-autos/
total 8
drwx------ 2 autos autos 4096 2017-11-09 18:48 ./
drwxrwxrwx 4 root         screen       4096 2017-11-09 18:48 ../

autos@autos.tech [~/bit]# screen -d
There is no screen to be detached.

autos@autos.tech [~/bit]# screen autos
Cannot access '11193dev/pts/0': No such file or directory

autos@autos.tech [~/bit]# screen -S autos
Cannot access '11193dev/pts/0': No such file or directory

autos@autos.tech [~/bit]# screen S-autos
Cannot access '11193dev/pts/0': No such file or directory
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like ypu don't have saved screen session.